# Mind control over Telekinetic field

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

How bad is it to try controlling an enemy with mind control? Does the chances increases depending on enemy type and/or distance and/or remaining health?

The telekinetic field can't fail, providing me with defence bonuses. Would the mind control really be worth it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Normal difficulty, a character with 60+ will and the Psi Armor has a very good chance to dominate anything organic that isn't an Ethereal or A Chrysalid even at full health.

Causing a few injuries (or preferably, using Mind Reave) significantly reduces their will and ratchets up your control success chance.

Mind-controlled enemies make ideal scouts, since absolutely nothing you care about gets hurt if they walk into an ambush. **edit**: Also, the enemy AI tends to prioritize by proximity, so they'll shoot your new "volunteer" first and give away their position.

Telekinetic field is /much/ more situational since it only lasts a very short time and requires proximity -- and Mutons and Floaters think "multiple XCom soldiers in proximity" rhymes with "Toss a grenade".

**edit** Downsides include:

1. Any aliens in your new 'volunteer forward scout's FoV trigger alert immediately; I've had one terror mission go south /really/ quickly when the muton I took control of could see three Chrysalids, a Floater spawn... *and* the Sectopod.
2. The alien gets control of itself back on *its* turn and you can't shoot it beforehand, so if you try to set it up for an ambush or stunbait, it gets a free shot back first.
3. <strike>This may be a bug, but your squad will get the "ally fallen in combat" willpower debuff if/when uncontrolled aliens blast your 'volunteer forward scout'.</strike> This has been fixed in a recent update.

Overall, I've gotten *much* more use out of mind control than TK field.

Comment: *"Mutons and Floaters think "multiple XCom soldiers in proximity" rhymes with "Toss a grenade""* -- Research project completed: *Alien Poetry* :)

Comment: `your squad will get the "ally fallen in combat"` I had sarcastic comments from the bad guys in the last mission when a mind controlled bad guy got killed. It made them seem quite amusingly stupid. :)